# replacing observations in sas

Tags: sas

I would like to assign  to some of the observations in the "ondays" variable below new values that depend on whether the variable "failure" is 0 or 1. Here my data set

```
    ID         X       ONDAYS       FAILURE
    1          0         59          1
    2          0        514          1
    3          0        313          0
    4          0        631          1
    5          0        107          1
    6          0         71          0
    7          0        583          1
    8          0         91          1
    9          0         66          1
   10          0         95          0
```

My goal is to sort ONDAYS---from lowest to highest (and I can do this)---to order values in ONDAYS and then create a new variable called "NEWDAYS" which will have the same value as in ONDAYS if FAILURE=1, but if FAILURE=0, NEWDAYS will be equal to closest (lower value) that correspond to a FAILURE=1 value in ONDAYS. 
For example in NEWDAYS observation 1 will equal to 59, but observation 6 will be equal to 66 (since the closest ordered "failure=1" value to 71 is 66).
Can you please help me how to do this?

Thanks.

Roland

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
data have;
input ID         X       ONDAYS       FAILURE;
datalines;
    1          0         59          1
    2          0        514          1
    3          0        313          0
    4          0        631          1
    5          0        107          1
    6          0         71          0
    7          0        583          1
    8          0         91          1
    9          0         66          1
   10          0         95          0
   ;;;;
run;
proc sort data=have;
by ondays;
run;
data want;
set have;
by ondays;
retain prev_ondays;
if failure=0 then new_ondays=prev_ondays;
else new_ondays=ondays;
output;
prev_ondays=new_ondays;
run;
```

Just keep track of the previous ONDAYS and assign it to the new ONDAYS if needed.

Another option: SQL.  This updates the current table, which might be desired and might not; if not, create a new table and apply this.

```
proc sql undopolicy=none;
update have H set ondays=(select max(ondays) from have V where H.ondays ge V.ondays and V.failure=1)
where failure=0;
quit;
```

Comment: good solution, however,I think you want to change "prev_ondays=ondays;" to "if failure=1 then prev_ondays=ondays;"...in case you have consecutive records with Failure=0

Comment: Nope.  That's handled by execution timing - as i've alrady changed ONDAYS to the previous ONDAYS value, the new PREV_ONDAYS is the value desired still (two or three or whatever rows ago).  This is why I don't use LAG - other than an irrational dislike for LAG - it's easier to manage the RETAIN variable across an unknown number of rows.

Comment: you're right...could have seen that if I had tested it with additional input data. The question did ask for newdays as an additional var rather than changing ondays, but your data step solution does work across any number of obs

Comment: @CarolinaJay65 It's almost what I wanted. The only glitch is that the variable PREV_ONDAYS starts with a . (missing value), so the remaining values are shifted down. Now I have in observation 2 what I expected for observation 1 and so forth

Comment: Also, not being used to proc sql, I didn't know how to use proc print to see what's coming out of this second option (sorry about my limitations in SAS)

Comment: I edited it to adjust for the 'new' variable request.  PREV_ONDAYS wasn't intended to be your new variable - I was adjusting the original variable.  New one is there now...
PROC SQL doesn't affect how the rest of SAS works, so PROC PRINT still works.  It's just updating the original table (not creating a new variable or anything like that).  If you want a new variable, go with the earlier solution.